# fatal: unable to access xxxxxx : The requested URL returned error: 503 al intentar pushear cambios al repositorio remoto

Tags: git, git-push, gitlab

Me salta este error cuando quiero pushear unos cambios al repositorio remoto. ¿Qué puede estar pasando?

```
Ariel@DESKTOP-7LC3VDM MINGW64 ~/Desktop/Great Leaf/great-leaf-ecuador (main)
$ git push origin main
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.com/semillero4/great-leaf-ecuador/-/tree/main/': The requested URL returned error: 503
```

Comment: Lectura altamente recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Creo que tienes mal configurado el URL del remoto. Cual es la salida de este comando? `git remote get-url origin`. Lo puedes colocar como mas información en la propia pregunta editándola.

Comment: Un error 503 suele ser un problema del servidor. Quizás no hay nada que puedas hacer salvo esperar a que se arregle. Aunque gitlab está funcionando ahora mismo sin problemas... ¿seguro que tienes tu repositorio remoto en gitlab?

Comment: hola abulafia
si el repositorio esta en gitLab pero esta en modo privado no se si por eso no me permite conectarme

Answer (score 0):

Probablemente tengas mal configurado el URL del repositorio. Debería ser (supongo) `https://gitlab.com/semillero4/great-leaf-ecuador.git` (verifica con `git remote get-url origin`).... Si es así, lo puedes arreglar con esto:

```
git remote set-url origin https://gitlab.com/semillero4/great-leaf-ecuador.git
```

Comment: muchas gracias eftshift0 por tu aporte, lo probare.